# Faster way Unique words frequency in NLTK

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

My dataframe has 2.3M rows. I am trying to get top 100 frequent words from this. I do not want punctuations, verbs, digits and ('a','the','an') I am using following query in python but takes forever to get results. Is there a quicker way to do it?

```
    import re
    import nltk
    # Download NLTK data if you haven't already
    nltk.download('punkt')
    nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')

    vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
    X = vectorizer.fit_transform(df['Comments_Final'])
    unique_words = sorted(vectorizer.get_feature_names())
    def count_words_without_punctuation_and_verbs(text):
        words = re.findall(r'\b\w+\b', text.lower())
        # Use NLTK to tag words and exclude verbs (VB* tags) and digits (CD tags)
        tagged_words = nltk.pos_tag(words)
        filtered_words = [word for word, pos in tagged_words if not pos.startswith('VB') and 
                          not pos == 'CD']
        return len(filtered_words)
   # Create a dictionary to store word frequencies
   word_frequencies = {}
   for word in unique_words:
   count = df['Comments_Final'].apply(count_words_without_punctuation_and_verbs).sum()
   word_frequencies[word] = count

   # Sort the words by frequency in descending order
   sorted_words = sorted(word_frequencies.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

   # Print the top 100 words
   for word, frequency in sorted_words[:100]:
   print(f"{word}: {frequency}")
```

Comment: Should not it be `vectorizer.get_feature_names_out()` ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Via the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.get_feature_names_out) and [Github](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7f9bad99d/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py#L1466), you're right. However, it seems that the code works for the original poster, albeit slowly, which is interesting.

Comment: By the way, it seems there's no connection between `word` and `count` within your loop `for word in unique_words: ...`, where `word` is just one of sorted features and the loop iteration is intended to process a df row (sentence)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a faster way. If you clean up your code a bit, you'll find it to be faster.

1. `def count_words_without_punctuation_and_verbs(text)`

Note how you call the above function later via `for` loop:

```
for word in unique_words:
   count = df['Comments_Final'].apply(count_words_without_punctuation_and_verbs).sum()
   word_frequencies[word] = count
```

The call to `count_words_without_punctuation_and_verbs()` in each iteration means that you are redundantly tokenizing/tagging *the entire DataFrame* every iteration, which is obviously super inefficient.

2. `return len(filtered_words)`

This is also redundant. `CountVectorizer` [can produce this number](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) as you use it to obtain your filtered words.

3. Mini-sidebar

Remember that you don't always need to use NLTK. For example, [`isdigit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) is generally faster than NLTK's `CD` for cardinal numbers.

Comment: It worked. It really sped up my query. Thank you very much.

Comment: @user21294168 I'm glad. If the answer was helpful, accepting it as the answer can help others find help more quickly for similar topics in the future.